# liquid syntax error ... unknown tag elsif

Tags: syntax, liquid

I am trying to create a nav for my jekyll / GitHub Pages site ... I have the following code for my nav ...

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
       {% for nav in site.data.nav %}
         (% if nav.subcategories != null %)
           <li>
             <a href="{{ site.url}}{{ nav.url}}">{{ nav.title }} &x25BC;</a>
              <ul>
                {% for subcategory in nav.subcategories %}
                  <li><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ subcategory.subhref }}">{{ subcategory.subtitle }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </li>
          {% elsif nav.title == page.title %}
            <li class="active"><a href="{{ nav.url }}">{{ nav.title }}</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ nav.href }}">{{ nav.title }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

When I run the jekyll server I get the following error:  Liquid syntax error (line 14): Unknown tag 'elsif'.

I have googled for several hours and every tutorial I've found says the elsif is a legitimate liquid tag.

Thank you to anyone you might be able to help!

Answer (score 2):

On line 4, you use parentheses instead of braces (curly brackets):

```
(% if nav.subcategories != null %)
```

should be:

```
{% if nav.subcategories != nil %}
```

Also, depending on your liquid environment, check for the *falsy* equivalent of an empty array. In Shopify you can use `empty` instead of `nil` or `[]` in jekyll.